# What is the difference between the rings $O_{(p)}$ and $O\left[\frac{1}{p} \right]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field. Let $O$ be its ring of integers. Let us denote by $O_{(p)}$ be the localisation of $O$ at the prime/maximal ideal $(p)$. Consider the another ring $O\left[\frac{1}{p} \right]$ obtained by inverting the prime $p$.

**My question:**

What is the difference between the rings $O_{(p)}$ and $O\left[\frac{1}{p} \right]$ ?

**Edit:** If $O=\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $O\left[\frac{1}{p} \right]=\mathbb{Q}_p$. But $O_{(p)}=(O \setminus \{(p)\})^{-1} O \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried? Where did you find this problem? How much theory are you familiar with?

Comment: Hint: Count the prime ideals of these rings. Maybe start with the case $O = \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Recall that localisation at a prime ideal means inverting everything *not* in that ideal!

Comment: @Servaes, It is a question I thought myself when reading $p$-adic algebraic number theory. I have explained the problem perfectly.

Comment: @TMO, The prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are $p\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p^2 \mathbb{Z}_p$, and so on. We have $\mathbb{Z}_p \left[\frac{1}{p} \right]=\text{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}_p)=\mathbb{Q}_p$. While the localisation of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ at $(p)$ is $(\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{(p)\})^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_p $ which is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, Thank you very much for the main point. Hence $O_{(p)}$ is a proper subset of $O \left[ \frac{1}{p} \right]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ a finite extension and $O$ its ring of integers then $(p)$ doesn't have to be a prime ideal, for example with $K=\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/2}),O=\Bbb{Z}_p[p^{-1/2}]$, the unique maximal ideal is $(p^{1/2})$. This is what we mean with "an uniformizer $\pi_K$": an element generating the maximal ideal.

We always have $(O-(\pi_K))^{-1}O = O$ and $O[p^{-1}]=K$.

Comment: Thanks. So in all cases,the localisation of $p$-adic ring of integer remains the same ring.  But do we prove $(O-(\pi_K))^{-1}O=O$ ?

Comment: It is the same as proving that $O$ has only one maximal ideal $m$, then $O^\times = O-m$.

Comment: ok, but in ordinary case rather DVR, for example, in ordinary set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, the localisation at a prime ideal $(p)$ is not same as $\mathbb{Z}$. For, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{p^n} \right] \supsetneq \mathbb{Z}$, where $n \geq 2$

Comment: Again $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$ means $(\Bbb{Z}-(p))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ which is $=\Bbb{Z}[\{ n^{-1},p\nmid n\}]$, very different to $\Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$. @Masmath

Comment: yes, I got the point now. Thanks